# change every cell value to zero in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have databases of users like below

```
good_user_mike
good_user_thomas
good_user_stevie
good_user_jhonathan
```

each database contains several tables eg `cpd,ce,ct,cg,cb,fd,gf`... which are all similar
they all contain a column names called

```
time,visitors,clicks,leads
1,12,42,12
2,12,45,25
3,42,45,43
..
.
.
```

Now my question is ,I want to make the row with `time = 3` of all tables of all databases to zero so that becomes

```
   time,visitors,clicks,leads
    1,12,42,12
    2,12,45,25
    3,0,0,0
    ..
    .
    .
```

is it possible to make every row with time = 3 to zero?

Comment: yes, of course... the first thing I would do however is normalize your data. Why are users databases separate? Why are these tables the same? It should be one table with users and another table with the other data, and a column to select user... that would simplify things immensely...
However, given one table `cpt` it would look like `UPDATE cpt SET visitors = 0,clicks=0,leads=0 WHERE time = 3`

Comment: @vignesh  Listen to serakfalcon.  It will make your life alot easier

Comment: @KyleK but sir is it possible to do it this way, this is for learning purpose..

Answer (score 0):

The code below will do that to all databases, note: you need mysql 5.0+ for it to work

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT distinct table_schema as database FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema != 'information_schema'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $tables = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = ".$row['database']);
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tables)) {
        $update = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE {$row2['table_name']} SET time = 0, visitors = 0, clicks = 0, leads = 0 WHERE time = 3");
    }
}
```

Comment: sir, I am getting 2 warning and its not making the values to zero: http://pastebin.com/ZdWVuzca